# $resource return an array of char instead of string like the answer of the server

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a service in angularJs that retrieve information from the server.
Using postman if i call this url http://localhost:8080/api/public/v1/indirizzo/zona?stradaId=5786&civico=53r the server answer with a string 0480170061900.

My service is

```
var resourceUrl =  'api/public/v1/indirizzo/:type';

    return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
        civico: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            params: {
                type: 'civico'
            },
            cache: true
        },
        autocomplete: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            params: {
                type: 'autocomplete'
            },
            cache: true
        },
        zona: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: falsem,
            params: {
                type: 'zona'
            },
            cache: true,
            transformResponse: []
        }
    });
```

In my controller I call 'zona' in this manner

```
function searchZona(stradaId, numeroCivico){
            vm.stradaId = stradaId;
            return Indirizzo.zona({stradaId: stradaId, civico: numeroCivico}).$promise.then(function(data){
                vm.zona = data;
                console.info("ZONA ID: ", vm.zona);
                return data;
            }, function(error){
                AlertService.error(error.data.message);
            });
        }
```

everything work correctly but vm.zona have this information

```
{"0":"0","1":"4","2":"8","3":"0","4":"1","5":"7","6":"0","7":"0","8":"6","9":"1","10":"9","11":"0","12":"0"}
```

why? Is possible to transform this in a string like the answer of the server?

Comment: In the $resource action object parameter, zona.isArray is set to falsem - is this a typo? else what is the value of falsem?

Comment: yes, is a typo, sorry

Comment: The `$resource` service does not work with string responses, only objects or arrays. If you wish to retrieve a string, use the `$http` service.

Comment: is not possible to manipulate the result with transformResponse?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

The AngularJS framework uses [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to populate the reference. If the source is not an object or array, nothing is copied.

The `transformResponse` function can transform a string response, but it must transform the response to either an array or an object in order to work with [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)